# Adding and removing borders dynamically to WebGL canvases

Tags: javascript, html, css, border

I have the following code for generating an html canvas:

```
<canvas id="glCanvas" class="canvases" width="20" height="20"></canvas>
```

and to set the colour I have the following:

```
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Is there an easy way to add and remove borders dynamically at run time? That is, when a specific if-statement condition is met, a red border is drawn around the canvas, and when this is no longer met the border is removed. Can this be done using either CSS/Javascript/WebGL?

Thank you

Comment: You can use a margin and a background color of the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with WebGL or canvases in particular. You can set a border on any element with something like

```
 someElement.style.border = "10px solid red";
```

And remove the border with

```
 someElement.style.border = "none";
```

For canvas I'd suggest you wrap the canvas in a div like this

```
 <div id="border"><canvas id="glCanvas"></canvas></div>
```

Then look up the div

```
 borderDiv = document.querySelector("#border");
```

And based on whatever conditions use code like that at the top;

```js
const borderDiv = document.querySelector("#border");
const showButton = document.querySelector("#show");
const hideButton = document.querySelector("#hide");

showButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  borderDiv.style.border = "10px solid red";
});

hideButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  borderDiv.style.border = "none";
});

// draw something in canvas. 
const gl = document.querySelector("#glCanvas").getContext("webgl");
gl.clearColor(0,0,1,1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

```css
#border { display: inline-block; }
#glCanvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }
```

```html
<div id="border"><canvas id="glCanvas"></canvas></div>
<div>
  <button id="show">show border</button>
  <button id="hide">hide border</button>
</div>
```

You can also do it be adding and removing styles

```
someElement.className = "styleWithBorder";
someElement.className = "styleWithoutBorder";
```

You can apply multiple classes by separating them with spaces

```
someElement.className = "style1 style2";
```

```js
const borderDiv = document.querySelector("#border");
const showButton = document.querySelector("#show");
const hideButton = document.querySelector("#hide");

showButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  borderDiv.className = "styleWithBorder";
});

hideButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  borderDiv.className = "";
});

// draw something in canvas. 
const gl = document.querySelector("#glCanvas").getContext("webgl");
gl.clearColor(0,0,1,1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

```css
/* these 2 lines make the border go inside the element
   instead of outside IF the element has a defined width and height */
html { box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/* this setting removes the default 5px margin on the body
   and makes the body fill the window so our div will match */
body { margin: 0; height: 100%; }

/* this line makes our border fill the body. We need to set
   the size so the border will go inside */
#border { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

/* this line makes the canvas fill the div it's inside
   and display:block makes it not add whitespace at the end */
#glCanvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }

/* here's our border */
.styleWithBorder { border: 10px solid yellow; }

/* make the ui show up over the rest */
#ui { position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 1em; }
```

```html
<div id="border"><canvas id="glCanvas"></canvas></div>
<div id="ui">
  <button id="show">show border</button>
  <button id="hide">hide border</button>
</div>
```